# Absolutely positioned div with zIndex -1 is hidden by Parent's children background-color

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to absolutely position an image on top of a parent div. The image has been given a negative zIndex (zIndex: -1) in order to simulate a background image (it has to be this way).  This parent div contains two child divs with two separate background-colors. I have tried giving the parent container a zIndex, but the image is still being hidden behind the children's background colors.  My desired result is an absolutely positioned image that maintains a -zIndex that is not hidden behind the background colors of the child divs. Keep in mind, if there is text in the child divs I don't want the image to cover that text.  My code is as follows:

```
    <div style={{ positon: "relative", zIndex: 0 }}>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red", height: 500, width: "100%" }}>TEXT</div>
      <div
        style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", height: 500, width: "100%" }}
      >TEXT</div>
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
          backgroundPosition: "cover",
          backgroundImage: `url(${Squiggle1})`,
          height: 600,
          width: 451,
          position: "absolute",
          top: 250,
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0,
          zIndex: -1
        }}
      />
    </div>
```

Comment: Actually the parent `div` has 3 child `div`s. What would you like to achieve? To have the div with the image above the red and the blue divs?

Comment: yes exactly @Azu

Answer (score 0):

your image is on the third child? not the parent!

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.one {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.two {
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.three {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.four {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: cover;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1663919009310-ecd1d054e09f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw3fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60");
  height: 600px;
  width: 451px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
  <div class="four" />
</div>
```

Comment: trying to simulate a background image effect, like i said in the question.  Otherwise I wouldn't have any issue just putting the image on top of the divs

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you need. I converted your code to pure HTML/CSS.

1. First, I closed the div with the image and instead of an image I used a yellow background to visualize it.
2. I changed its z-index to 1 to be on the top of the other divs.

```html
<div style="positon: relative; z-index: 0">
      <div style="background-color: red; height: 500px; width: 100%; position:relative;z-index:-2">TEXT</div>
      <div style="background-color:blue; height: 500px; width: 100%; position:relative;z-index:-2"></div>
      <div style="background-color:yellow;height: 600px;width: 451px;position: absolute;top: 250px;bottom: 0;right: 0;z-index:-1"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The issue is it will also sit on top of text within the divs etc; hence the negative zindex

Comment: If you need z-index to be -1, then give the other divs z-indexes -2.

Comment: doing so hides the image

Comment: I've updated my sample above. I've added `position:relative;z-index:-2` to the red and the blue divs. And `z-index:-1` to the yellow one.

Comment: It will still cover text etc on the red and blue divs, is it possible to have the yellow div act like a background image

Comment: I don't get your idea. Could you place the text because I have no idea where it should be?

Comment: added text to the example

Comment: I am trying to simulate a background image, but it has to be done with absolute positioning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248302/discussion-between-azu-and-rob-terrell).